# Equations are not being formatted when I append new equation MathJax

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I am facing a problem using mathjax. the equations already available are formatted but the equations that I put by myself are not being formatted.

here is my code:

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script async="true" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@2/MathJax.js?config=AM_CHTML">
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="eq">
    <button onclick="amb()">equation</button>
    <p id="amb"></p>
    <p>`x^3`</p>
    <script>
        function amb() {
            eq = document.getElementById('eq').value;
            document.getElementById('amb').append("`" + eq + "`");
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I suggest use a `form` and a `type=submit` button for a better UX.
I found the solution you need to queue an action to rescan the page: `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);`

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <script async="true" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@2/MathJax.js?config=AM_CHTML">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form onsubmit="amb(); return false">
    <input type="text" id="eq">
    <input type="submit"  value="equation">
  </form>
  <p id="amb"></p>
  <p>`x^3`</p>
  <script>
    function amb() {
      eq = document.getElementById('eq').value;
      document.getElementById('amb').innerText = ("`" + eq + "`");
      MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
      
    }

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```